# Spring Fox Swagger UI Mask Password

Tags: java, swagger, swagger-ui, springfox

I have a Spring Fox Swagger UI where I perform a number of operations, one of which is posting to Jira and it requires a user to input their username and password.

This issue is the password does not mask.

[image: Password field not masking]

```
public ResponseEntity<?> createJiraIssue( @RequestParam(value = "jiraProject") @ApiParam(value = ParamConfig.PROJECT_DESC) String jiraProject,                                            
@RequestParam(value = "qcPassword", required = false) @ApiParam(type = "string",  format = "password", value = ParamConfig.QC_PASSWORD) String qcPassword ) throws CustomException,
                                                                                                                                                                                    IOException,
                                                                                                                                                                                    URISyntaxException
```

I added the `type = "string", format = "password"` but it made no difference.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a known issue which currently is not fixed

https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-core/issues/469
https://github.com/springfox/springfox/issues/2366

There are no workaround for this at the current moment.

Comment: https://github.com/springfox/springfox/issues/3002

Just noticed this as well myself. Thanks for your response. I guess my only option is to wait.